# add facebook fans count in a smarty template // Prestashop

Tags: facebook, smarty, prestashop

I'm looking to add the number of my facebook's fans into my prestashop template. As a smarty variable, so it updates everytime.

I have found some code to do it in php :

```
<?php
require_once('facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'your_app_id',
'secret' => 'your_app_secret',
'cookie' => true,
));
$result = $facebook->api(array(
'method' => 'fql.query',
'query' => 'select fan_count from page where page_id = your_page_id;'
));
$fb_fans = $result[0]['fan_count'];
?>
```

or simpler :

```
<?php
        $page_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
        $xml = @simplexml_load_file("http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=facebook.fql.query&query=SELECT%20fan_count%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id=".$page_id."") or die ("a lot");
        $fans = $xml->page->fan_count;
        echo $fans;
?>
```

What's the best way to add the PHP to a smarty template .tpl ?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you please let me know where you want to add that count in your page(s), header section, footer section or on a specific page? Let me know and i will write you a detailed answer for your required place.

Comment: Thanks, altafhussain, I just found the answer for my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, Vekia from Prestashop forum help me, this is the best answer to my question :

( Note : this works when add it into the footer.tpl)

go to the file:

classes/controller/FrontController.php

add somewhere in the class this function:

```
public static function fbcount($idpage){
        $ch = curl_init("http://graph.facebook.com/$idpage");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $raw = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $data = json_decode($raw);
        return $data->likes;
}
```

then in the footer.tpl file you can use this:

```
{FrontController::fbcount('399888213399907')}
```

where the 399888213399907 is id of your page

enjoy!